# How do I keep quotations in variable used with PHP string

Tags: php, string, variables

I am using a custom php query by submitting a custom search form. Everything works great except for if a string calls a name like O'Reilly, the search will come up with no results for O\'Reilly instead of O'Reilly. I am using the following to call the variable:

```
$fullname=trim($_REQUEST["fullname"]);
```

and this is my php header

```
 header("Location: http://example.com/results?patientid=$patientid&fullname=$fullname&date=$date");
```

That will redirect to the search results page where I have the following code for the fullname:

```
             $patientid=trim($_REQUEST["patientid"]);
             $fullname=trim($_REQUEST["fullname"]);
             $date=trim($_REQUEST["date"]);
```

Then I echo that and it comes up O/'Reilly with the slash in it and no results.

Should be O'Reilly

Comment: Do you have magic quotes on? What version of PHP are you running? http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: How do I turn magic quotes on? Through cpanel?

Comment: Don't turn them on, you don't want them. They cause the escaping you've mentioned. If they are on turn them off. Also you may be open to SQL injections with this code are you parameterizing your queries?

Comment: I tried turning them off and the php.ini file is not taking any effect. It is godaddy so I am not sure how to turn them off. It is only a search query, so I don't see how. I am using wordpress. Does that make any different in pulling the string?

Comment: Try this article out, https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8383/disable-magic-quotes.

Comment: Ok I copied over the runtime version and what it does is strips 2 of the 3 slashes. It still leaves one. Hmm

Comment: That's strange behavior. I'd try contact the support, tell them you already used that doc as well to save some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Magic Quotes` is `On` It automatically escapes incoming data to the PHP script. This feature has been DEPRECATED as of `PHP 5.3.0` and REMOVED as of `PHP 5.4.0`. When on, all `'` (single-quote), `"` (double quote), `\` (backslash) and `NULL` characters are escaped with a backslash automatically. `magic_quotes_gpc` Affects HTTP Request data (GET, POST, and COOKIE). Cannot be set at runtime, and defaults to on in PHP.

Comment: I am running php version 5.2. Right now the magic quotes is on. I tried turning them off by creating a php.ini in my directory and it didn't effect it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
             $fullname=trim($_REQUEST["fullname"]);
             $fullname = stripslashes($fullname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh, you definitely want to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) those...

```
header("Location: http://example.com/results?patientid=".urlencode($patientid)."&fullname=".urlencode($fullname)."&date=".urlencode($date));
```

But you know what's even better? [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
var $query_string = http_build_query(array(
  "fullname" => $fullname,
  "patientid" => $patientid,
  "date" => $date
));

header("Location: http://example.com/results?{$query_string}");
```

Comment: No need to be sorry! If you have any more trouble, let me know.

Comment: Now it comes up with O\\\'Reilly

Comment: I will try your new query!

Comment: How would I call the results $query_string on the other side with separate variables?